# Rewrite $y = a \cdot (b/c) $ to prevent division by zero, if $c = 0$.

Tags: functions

Is it possible to rewrite this formula to prevent eventually divisions by 0.

The equation is used in a program, and I just wanted to know if I could skip the if statement.

The equation is: $y = a \cdot (b/c) $

Comment: Well, what should $y$ be if $c = 0$?

Comment: No. But you can compute $yc$ instead of $y$, of course, and push the potential problem of dealing with $c=0$ further down the line.

Comment: if c = 0 then y = 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, no. In some cases, yes. It depends on how $a$, $b$, and $c$ relate to each other. For example, if $a=cx$, then you can rewrite this: $a(b/c)=cx(b/c)=xb$. Of course, the modified function may not be *meaningful* at $c=0$, but it won't throw an error. In general, keep your if statement. Unless you're dealing with floating point, in which case you should handle everything a bit differently (fun times!).

Comment: Floating point land: Where commutativity works just sometimes, and $0.3$ is never actually $0.3$.

Comment: I kept the if statement, but thanks for the answer :)